# Transistor overheating in a linear power supply

Tags: power-supply, transistors, circuit-design

I'm a novice electronics engineer and as I was trying to fix an old linear power supply of a video door phone system, I found something interesting.

First a little info about the power supply. This power supply works as intended with some of its features (12 VDC and 12 VAC outputs) but on the 18 VDC timed output it has a problem.

When the control signal (a button is pressed) from the door station then a relay is energized and 18 VDC output is fed to the monitors and camera. You can set the time with a potentiometer from 20 seconds to 90 seconds. The problem is that when some seconds have passed after the button is pressed, the relay starts to bounce on and off for some seconds and then to off. This happens only when the time is about to run out.

I have checked all the components with my multimeter and they seem to work fine (resistors capacitors diodes etc.)

As I was searching I noticed that when the time is running out the right transistor (red circle check image) of the darlington pair is overheating. I removed it from the circuit but all the tests seem to be ok (DMM diode test and hfe). I decided to replace it with a new one and then i tested the circuit that works as intended. No relay chattering and not transistor over heating problem.

Transistor is BC 337-25.

How is this possible and how I can check a transistor for this kind of problem?

I attach an image of the circuit. There are no components beneath the PCB.

[image: Pcb of the power supply]

Comment: After testing the transistor, did you replace it with a new one or just re-insert it? If the latter, does it no longer get hot? When you say the circuit works as intended now, does this mean you believe you successfully repaired the device? Therefore, are you effectively asking how simply removing and re-inserting the transistor could contribute to the repair?

Comment: I inserted a new transistor to the pcb and then tested the 18VDC timed output and it was working as intended. Also the relay wasn't bouncing on and off when the time was running out.

Comment: Please edit your post to include a schematic of the device in question, and include datasheet links to any relevant parts e.g. ICs, transistors. On a repair basis, this probably requires reverse-engineering the board, which isn't too hard to do on such a simple circuit. Like many curiosities, this is not one we can answer without you putting in some effort to find the answer yourself.

Answer (score 1):

> How is this possible and how I can check a transistor for this kind of problem?

A curve tracer would be needed to really make sure that the static performance curves of the transistor are within datasheet specs.

hFE meters are often poorly implemented. I'd much rather put together a little circuit with a couple op-amps to measure the current gain in a few operating points, absent a curve tracer.

A basic curve tracer for transistors operating in a narrow-ish range of currents and voltages can be made for very little money if you have the time for it.